# DocuSign API: Can I sign and attach documents without embedded signing

Tags: angularjs, docusignapi

Sorry, if I'm using the wrong terminology.

I'm using an AngularJS form that's sending the form data to my DocuSign template and filling in the corresponding fields, so all good there.

As far as I can tell, to begin the embedded signing event I have to retrieve the signing URL, which directs the signer to my document through DocuSign, where they then add their signature.

My question is, is there a way to capture the signature and file uploads through my AngularJS application, and prevent the user from having to view my DocuSign template altogether?

Comment: Do you want to capture the signature without showing the document the Signer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a recipient to electronically sign a document via DocuSign, then the recipient will need to be accessing the DocuSign signing experience (through embedded or remote signing). There is not an option for you to capture the users signature within your own app and then have that applied via an API call to a document. Signing is an explicit action within the DocuSign signing experience which the user must make/apply.